# Why it says 'expected unqualified-id before numeric constant' even though i only use const int?

Tags: c++

As a struggling newbie, I really dont understand why I keep getting errors at line 19, 33, 35 and so on. I'm literally following the modules that my teacher gave me and boom these errors haunting me for 3 days. Anw, my teacher use Visual Studio 2013 while I use Dev C++, is that giving any differences to the script? If yes then please tell me what should I do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stack>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std; 

const int MAX = 50;
class infix{
private:
        char target[MAX], stack[MAX];
        char *s, *t;
        int top, 1;

public:
        infix();
        void setexpr(char *str);
        void push(char c);
        char pop();
        void convert();
        int priority(char c);
        void show();
};

infix::infix(){
        top = -1;
        strcpy(target, "");
        strcpy(stack, "");
        1 = 0;
}

void infix::setexpr(char *str){
        s=str;
        _strrev(s);
        1 = strlen(s);
        *(target + 1) = '\0';
        t = target + (l - 1);
}

void infix::push(char c){
        if (top == MAX - 1)
            cout<<"\nStack is full\n";
        else{
            top++;
            stack[top] = c;
    }
}

char infix::pop(){
        if (top -1){
            cout<<"Stack is empty\n";
            return -1;
        }
        else{
        char item=stack[top];
        top--;
        return item;
    }
}

void infix ::convert(){
        char opr;
        while (*s){
            if (*s == ' ' || *s == '\t') { 
                s++;
                 continue; 
                } 
 
            if (isdigit(*s) || isalpha(*s)){
                while (isdigit(*s) || isalpha(*s)){ 
                    *t = *s; 
                    s++; 
                    t--; 
                } 
        } 
 
            if (*s == ')'){ 
                push(*s); 
                s++; 
            } 
 
            if (*s == '*' || *s == '+' || *s == '/' || *s == '%' || *s == '-' || *s == '$'){ 
                if (top != -1){ 
                    opr = pop();
                    while (priority(opr) > priority(*s)){
                    
                    *t = opr; 
                    t--; 
                    opr = pop(); 
                } 
                push(opr); 
                push(*s); 
 }
            else
                push(*s); 

            s++;
 }
 
            if (*s == '('){
            opr = pop();
            while ((opr) != ')'){
                *t = opr;
                t--;
                opr = pop();
            }
            s++;
        }
 }
 
            while (top != -1){
            opr = pop();
            *t = opr;
            t--;
        }
        t++;
}

int infix::priority(char c){
        if(c == '$')
            return 3;
        if(c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '%')
            return 2;
        else{
                if(c == '+' || c == '-')
                    return 1;
                else
                    return 0;
        }
}

void infix::show(){
        while (*t){
            cout<<" "<<*t;
            t++;
    }
}

void main(){
        char expr[MAX];
        infix q;
        cout<<"\nMasukan Sebuah Ekspresi infix : ";
        cin.getline(expr, MAX);
        q.setexpr(expr);
        q.convert();
        cout<<"Hasil konversi kedalam notasi prefix adalah: ";
         q.show();
        _getch();
    }
```

Comment: We can't see line numbers. Please add a comment next to the lines that give errors, and also paste the exact text of the error messages.

Comment: In C++ the global `main` function is required to have the return type `int`. It isn't `void`.

Comment: Did you copy this by reading the code? You seem to have `1` in a bunch of places where you should have `l`.

Comment: `1 = 0;` <-- makes my head hurt :)

Comment: This is but one of the reasons why single-letter variables are a bad idea. if `l`  was `length`, not only would it make the code easier to read, this mistake almost certainly would never have happened.

Comment: actually i dont understand any of this, i just following the script that my teacher gave to me.........

Comment: This is *way too much* code to be given if you've just started learning the language, not to mention that the code is pretty bad. I suggest referring to some other materials, such as text books, to start learning the basics.

Comment: there's also an `l` appearing out of nowhere in the `setexpr` function

Comment: Understanding is an absolute must if you need to get a good grade on the material. Sometimes this means you need to step back and go over some less advanced material  to build up that understanding before returning to the problem at hand.

Comment: I know, im starting to learn basics this year but i keep getting codes like this to learn from. Thats why im ended up confused every session, not to mention how cooperative my teacher was. Thank you for helping me anyway!

Comment: I don't know about Dev++ but I know Visual Studio would tell you you can't have a variable start with a number, and where you have undefined variables in use (e.g. using `l` instead of `1`).

Answer (score 3):

Variable names cannot start with a number.
You have a variable named `1`, which is not allowed in c++.